is it possible to optimize a curve fitting where a variable depend on another?
I'm wondering if it is possible to make a curve fitting od a dual exponential where the parameter b is strictly superior to the parameter d?.
I don't understand how I can add such a constraint.
Here's a minimal example
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = np.linspace(0,4,50) # Example data

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c * np.exp(d * x)

y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5) # Example exponential data

# Here you give the initial parameters for a,b,c which Python then iterates over
# to find the best fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0))


The implementation of curve_fit only allows you to specify bounds on the parameters independent of all other parameters.

Can you give a representative example of your problem? As written, the two terms are identical, so you could just swap them if b turns out less than d. One solution is to use minimize. You can make the objective function the sum squared error, and it allows you to add any constraints you wish.

Try by using different starting values for b and d. If not enough, boundaries can be added. In general one knows what approximated range of the parameters make sense.

Is it possible in general? Yes - is it possible with curve_fit? No.
If your target function isn't fake, then you also need bounds and should probably fit on the log scale; I don't show that.
Also, strictly superior makes it sound like a greater-than, which is not typically possible in numerical optimization. Use greater-equal, and if that's a problem, add some tiny epsilon.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint


def func(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*np.exp(b*x) + c*np.exp(d*x)


def least_squares(abcd: np.ndarray, x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray)-> float:
    y_actual = func(x, *abcd)
    error = y - y_actual
    return error.dot(error)


def main() -> None:
    # Example data
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    x = np.linspace(0,4,50)
    y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5) * rand.uniform(low=0.9, high=1.1, size=x.size)

    p0 = 2.4, 1.2, 0.4, 0.6

    result = minimize(
        fun=least_squares, x0=p0, args=(x, y),
        # b >= d
        constraints=LinearConstraint(
            A=(0, 1, 0, -1),
            lb=0,
        ),
    )
    
    # assert result.success, result.message
    # would fail due to lack of bounds, poor initial guess, and failure to fit on the log scale
    
    print(result.x)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.semilogy(x, y, label='experiment')
    ax.semilogy(x, func(x, *p0), label='estimate')
    ax.semilogy(x, func(x, *result.x), label='fit')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


